# How to query property value when property name is a parameter?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Typically we can query property value for something like:

```
Match (n:Product)
where n.name="iPhone X"
return n
```

However, in my case, I don't know which property I should match, but I only know the value, in which case the property name becomes a kind of variable. I want something like this:

```
Match (n:Product)
    where n.{name}="iPhone X"
    return n
```

or with relationship variable r:

```
Match (n:Product)-[{r}]->(c:Color {name:'white'})
```

In both cases, in my application I know some property or relationship **value** beforehand, without knowing specifically which property it should match against.

Is this query based on property or relationship values supported in Neo4j or spring-data-neo4j?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer to user Neo4j Browser parameters. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in this example:

```
CREATE (:Node {name : 'Bruno'})-[r:REL_TYPE]->()
```

Setting Neo4j Browser parameters:

```
:param {prop : 'name', rel_type : 'REL_TYPE'}
```

Then querying:

```
MATCH (n:Node) 
WHERE n[{prop}] = "Bruno"
RETURN n
```

The result:

```
╒════════════════╕
│"n"             │
╞════════════════╡
│{"name":"Bruno"}│
└────────────────┘
```

That is: you can use the property name as a key enclosed in square brackets in the `WHERE` clause.

An workaround to query by dynamic relationship types can be using the [type()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-type) function, this way:

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r]->()
WHERE type(r) = {rel_type}
return r
```

Comment: that's great! So I can have variables for property name, property value and relationship. What about variable for node label? I learnt that it's not possible. Right?

Comment: @user697911 Well, you can use `labels()` function: `match (n)
where 'Node' in labels(n) 
return n`

But this way you are degrading your performance because the label index is not used.

Comment: So the property name and relationship variables don't affect performance too much?

Comment: @user697911 unfortunately in tests I have done now the index in the name property are not used with the dynamic key. The index are used only when the property is used as a constant (`WHERE n.name = "Bruno"`).

Comment: I see. That's good to know. In cases where performance isn't an bottleneck, it can be used.

Comment: A second thought, It turns out that my original question is something differently. I am asking in another thread.

Comment: Hi, Bruno and Cybersam, please see this and its my original intended question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913965/how-to-query-the-graph-when-the-intended-property-name-is-unknown

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly in the MATCH clause? In the WHERE makes it a lot slower.