# How to query the graph when the intended property name is unknown?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A related question is here:
[How to query property value when property name is a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912487/how-to-query-property-value-when-property-name-is-a-parameter)

Let's say if I want to ask "Recommend me 500-dollar phones". And in my graph, I have:

```
create (p:Product {name:"iPhone 1", price:"500", color:"white"})
create (p:Product {name:"iPhone 2", price:"400", color:"white"})
create (p:Product {name:"iPhone 3", price:"800", color:"black"})
```

Based on the language "Recommend me 500-dollar phones", I know I should query on the Product node, but I don't know the 'price' property. I just want to match any product node with some property value = "500". In this case, how to achieve this in the query?

```
Match(p:Product) where p.x = 500
```

Here I don't know what "x" is and I don't have a property name for x to accept. Is this possible?

EDITED:

```
match (p:Product)
where any(key in keys(node) where key contains 'TEST')
RETURN p.key
```

How to return the 'p.key' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your `[EDITED]` question is asking, so here are answers to 2 possible interpretations:

1. If you know that the **property key(s) of interest** contain the string "TEST", and you want to get their distinct property values:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Product)
   WITH p, [k in KEYS(p) WHERE k CONTAINS 'TEST' | p[k]] AS values
   UNWIND values AS value
   RETURN DISTINCT value;
   ```
2. If you know that the **property value(s) of interest** contain the string "TEST", and you want to get the distinct values:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Product)
   WITH p, [k in KEYS(p) WHERE p[k] CONTAINS 'TEST' | p[k]] AS values
   UNWIND values AS value
   RETURN DISTINCT value;
   ```

The `UNWIND` operation produces no rows if the list being unwound is empty.

*Please note that these queries are expensive, since they have to scan every property of every `Product` node.*

Comment: for matched 'key', I want to return the key's value from this node.

Comment: The first one seems to be my need.

Comment: What's the | p[k] for?

Comment: See the [documentation for the list comprehension syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension).

Comment: if I know that there is only one key that can match the CONTAINS condition, can the query be simplified a bit? In that case I don't need to put into a list p[k]?

Comment: You are probably not going to get it any simpler using just Cypher.

Comment: @user697911 I think this question has evolved to some new issues... So maybe you should accept this as the right answer and make ask new questions, If you need.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do an workaround using [any()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-any) and [keys()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) functions, but I think this is not recommended because you are iterating over **all** node properties and Neo4j will ignore all property indexes:

```
match (node:Product)
where any(key in keys(node) WHERE node[key] = "500")
RETURN node
```

Comment: So it's a performance issue. Maybe we can use more machine power to overcome that.

Comment: Or I can extract all properties with associated values from the graph, build a dictionary, and use this dictionary to look up to determine the property key before forming the query.

Comment: you can also use a secondary index like with this apoc procedure: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_full_text_search

Comment: @Bruno, if I don't want to return the whole 'node', but only the value of node[key], is there a way to do that? In the query above, if I return node.key, it seems the "key" is out of scope.

Comment: @user697911 but in your scenario you know the value... Then you can simply return it back: `match (node:Product)
where any(key in keys(node) WHERE node[key] = "500")
RETURN "500"`

Comment: @BrunoPeres. I added my question those are all similar query requirements. In that case, how to return the 'p.key'?